# C# Clear the private list data from Nunit testcase (newbie)

Tags: c#, list, class, nunit, system.reflection

I want to set the default values to `variables` and `list` while testing my code using `Nunit`.

My code

```
public class Myclass
    {
        static bool isShown = false;
        protected static List<string> registery = new List<string>();
        //My code
    }
```

I need to change the default value. Because every test case this value will be changed.

I am using `NUnit` to test my application. I tried some thing by referring [this](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-Attribute). But it is not working.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class MyclassTest
    {
        Myclass obj = new Myclass();

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("isShown ", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(obj, false);
            typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("registery", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(obj, null);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("isShown ", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(obj, false);
            typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("registery", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(obj, null);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test01()
        {
          // Test case
        }
   }
```

Could you any one please help me to get rid from this?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Exceptions? Unexpected results? Compiler-errors? Apart from this you don´t need the `GetField`-bindingflag to set the value of a field via reflection. But as your both fields are `static`, you should use `Bindingflags.Static` instead of `Instance`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you! It works when I change the `Instance` to `Static`. But How can I remove old data from `List`.

Comment: I just initialized the `List` Now its working. Thank you @HimBromBeere

Comment: To delete old data just set the `register`-fields value to `new List<string>()` instead of `null` in your `Cleanup`-code.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you get some `NullReferenceException`, because the requested field was not found. This is caused by your `BindingFlags`. In order set a private static field you´ll need this:

```
typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("isShown ", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(obj, false);
```

To avoid such errors in the future you should definitly add some null-checks before:

```
var field = typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("isShown ", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
if(field != null)
    field.SetValue(obj, false);
else
    throw new Exception(...);
```

Comment: Its working when I am changing the `Instance` to `Static`. But How can I remove the old data from `List`

Answer (score 0):

```
[TearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("isShown ", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(obj, false);
        typeof(FusionLicenseProvider).GetField("registery", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(obj, New List<string>());
    }
```

These code is worked for me.